# React state depending on another state ( Form input validation )

Tags: reactjs, forms, object, asynchronous

```
  const handleValidation = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let errors = {};
    let formIsValid = true;

    setForm((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));

    //Name
    if (!form.name) {
      formIsValid = false;
      errors["name"] = "Cannot be empty";
    }

    //Email
    if (!form.email) {
      formIsValid = false;
      errors["email"] = "Cannot be empty";
    }

    //Message
    if (!form.message) {
      formIsValid = false;
      errors["message"] = "Cannot be empty";
    }

    setError(JSON.stringify(errors));
    setFormValid(formIsValid);
  };
```

Got this handleValidation function thats setting the formState properly, all good.
Then few more lines beneath the newly set form values are getting checked for validation, the problem is that its based on the previous values

How could I make this work so its checked based upon the latest values?

Comment: Do that in a separate `useEffect` triggered on the value of `form`.

Comment: Why not check the value directly?

Comment: B45i, id wanna have some proper validation, this is just an example, thats why the function

jonrsharpe, ill look into it thanks for the tip